# Google Chrome on Windows: Undo Minimize/ Maximize/ Close Style

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

Is there any way to force Google Chrome (Windows XP Pro) to use the "normal" Windows UI controls in the upper right (Minimize/ Maximize (Resize)/ Close)? It's frustrating to try to minimize a couple of programs at the same time and then realize you have to move the mouse around to do so.

Answer (score 2):

When I open Google Chrome, my standard UI controls are the ones you say you need to force to use.  Aren't these the default?  Can you clarify what yo mean by "force to use normal?"  Is you browser stuck on full screen mode?  If so, you can exit by hitting F11 or clicking the link at the top when in full screen mode.

Comment: Google Chrome's close button is wider than the Windows XP default. If you have a several maximized windows that you want to minimize, and you start clicking the space where the minimize button is repeatedly, you will minimize the other windows, but will end up closing or restoring Google Chrome.

Comment: What Bavi said. I'm not stuck in a full-screen mode, this is just in the normal view. I want it to use the normal Windows controls or at least something the proper width, not the stretched ones they provide.

Comment: Ah, I see...  My apologies.  I see what you mean.  Have you ventured over to the Google Help Forum?